# Use the first principles to find the largest or the smallest values of x in the x direction when $ = -1$ of $f(x,y) = ( 2x-3y)^{1/2}$

Tags: calculus

I used the general formula of first principles $f(x,y) = \frac{f(x,y + h) - f(x,y)}h$, and then I found the derivative to be $1/(2x+3)^{1/2}$. I then tried to solve for $x$ and found $x$ to be $x= -3/2$ but using the second derivative test yields to an undefined solution.

Answer (score 0):

When y = -1, you're looking at $\sqrt{2x + 3}$.
If perchance f is a real value function,
then -3/2 <= x is mandated.

Comment: I don't quiet understand.

Comment: You you said you are looking for the smallest value of x when y = -1. 
f(x,-1) = as I wrote.  You not looking for the smallest value of f(x,-1). so differentiating by x does not apply.

Comment: Please give me a hint sir, because I have been struggling with this for a while now. Would differentiating in y make a difference ?

Comment: Get it clear.  Are you looking for the smallest value of x or of the smallest value of f?

Comment: As I so mentioned in the question, im looking for the largest or smallest value of x in the x direction

Comment: Is f a real valued function?  If so, then x,y have to be chosen so that the square root is not imaginary.  So look at f(x,-1) again and understand that some x's will cause f to be imaginary.